# Can't find mvc folder in htdocs

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to create  aproject in phalcon. I downloaded and installed the phalcon and the phalcon web tools from this page.  I see the phalcon extansion when execute this:`<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>`.
The problem is I don't see a phalcon folder created in htdocs containing the mvc.I downloaded phalcon web tools,changed the path of env var according to this link https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/tools.html and then open localhost/info/ and the object is not found is the result.Where can I start a new project? Or should I create by myself a folder?Thanks!

Comment: If you need to look at this source, it's written in [zephir](https://zephir-lang.com/) (a language created by the phalcon team that mediates between C and PHP for creating PHP extensions). You can see the easy-to-follow Phalcon source here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/master/phalcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phalcon is installed as php extension - so this is why no any files. Just use devtools - https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/tools.html

Comment: Is it possible to have these system var path: C:\xampp\php;C:\phalcon-tools ?